# How to save the last selected language using-sharedpreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, multilingual

I am adding multiple language facility in my android app. Whenever I change the language it changes fine. But after reopening the app its again showing the choose language screen. I want to save the last selected language, so next time when user reopen the app it should not show the choose language screen it should directly go to the next page and should display the items in the language which was last selected.
What to do? Any solutions? Please check the below code. In this code where i have to store in SharedPreferences and where i have to get the sharedpreference

```
public class lang extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    Locale myLocale;
    String currentLanguage = "en", currentLang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lang);

        currentLanguage = getIntent().getStringExtra(currentLang);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Select language");
        list.add("English");
        list.add("Español");
        list.add("Français");
        list.add("Hindi");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setLocale("en");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setLocale("es");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setLocale("fr");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setLocale("hi");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void setLocale(String localeName) {
        if (!localeName.equals(currentLanguage)) {
            myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
            startActivity(refresh);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(lang.this, "Language already selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to add the check just before you call/launch this "lang" activity

Comment: where i add sharedprefrance

Comment: You can add it in the setLocale() function

Comment: plez if u dont mind plez write for me i wll be very thanks full

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an AppPreference class and save your data in the Shared Preference like this:-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

            private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;


    public static String getSelectdLanguage(Context ctx) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            return mPrefs.getString("language", "");
        }

        public static void setSelectdLanguage(Context ctx, String value) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mPrefsEditor.putString("language", value);
            mPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

public static void clearAllPreferences(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.clear();
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
        }
```

to save your selected language call this method:-

```
AppPreference.setSelectdLanguage(this, "selected language");
```

and to get your selected from shared preference :-

```
String selectdLanguage = AppPreference.getSelectedLanguage(this);
```

Comment: AppPreference.setSelectdLanguage(this, "selected language");
.
String selectdLanguage = AppPreference.getSelectedLanguage(this);
where  i put these two lin?

Comment: when you select a language and getting the selected language

Comment: set the language in onItemSelected